# How to get a node key from inner matching values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the key of each event that match the users ID's that I have looped before in another table, so, I have this table where the current userID that is logged in has a list of users that will assist to a certain event

[image]

Im logged in as the user `MUTzo13NuJRlbbkZCDp2nCdHkIn1` , then I just get all the users below that id , so I know which one I invited

I have done that with this

```
 mDatabase.child("userEvent").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        final String users = snapshot1.getKey();

...
```

So , now my string of users has all the users from the current logged in one.

Now, since I have all those users that belongs to the logged in one , I want to loop another table, find the matching users and get the key (the event ID in which those users has not assisted)

Table events

[image]

I need to get for example the ID `LT9d-sJCmMBUIW14AG8` if the users looped before are inside of it, so I just tried this

```
mDatabase.child("userEvent").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        final String user = snapshot1.getKey();

                        //Now I go to the events table and try to get the event ID if those users are inside of them
                        mDatabase.child("events").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                  for(DataSnapshot snapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                                    if(snapshot2.equals(user))
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: "+snapshot2.getKey());

                                }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

But it does not work, instead getKey returns the name node events, instead of the name of the node that the user belongs.

Any tip ?

EDIT:

Thanks Peter for the answer, I'm having a trouble that is the users are beign matched with events that they dont belong to

[image]

So , the problem is that its matching to events users that It does not belong to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
mDatabase.child("events").orderByChild(user).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           String keys = snapshot2.getKey();
       }
    }
  }

   @Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

You need to add the `user` String that you retrieved in the first listener inside `orderByChild()` and then you will get a snapshot that contains that child. After looping you will be able to get the parent key of that child.

Comment: yep, this is working fine peter, thanks, but the only thing is that its asigning the all the users found in the first loop in all the events instead of just giving me the event for that user

Comment: Because I need to know if the userID inside events is the same as the user that has my first query, if thats true, just return the key of that matching user with that event

Comment: inside that for to get the key of the user I need to know if that user is the same as its beign queried, and match to get the key, because it will return the key of the event even for users that does not belong inside that event

Comment: The `keys` variable in the code that i provided should be giving u the keys where the id `users` belong. So it should give you this `LT9d-sJCmMBUIW14AG8` and the other id.

Comment: yep, instead it gives to me the keys of all the events but the users who does not belong to that events are having those keys too , take a look at the edit

Comment: I think that I need to place an if(snapshot.getvalue().equals(user)) to see if the user matchs the user below events, but snapshot.getvalue does not brings the userid inside events, any clue peter?

Comment: not sure I'm thinking about it.. the thing is when you query, you are going to get the `keys` where that `userid` belongs, but if there are other `ids` under that key, you will also retrieve them, because they are all under that event id so actually they all belong to that event. Example: this id: `-LTDnx0R6s26iG-Lk81Q` you will retrieve this key since the `userid` belongs to it, but also other ids belong to it as well so you will also retrieve those.. so probably best to change the database to meet the query that you want

Comment: yep , thats right but at the G8 key, the first one with one user below it, it brings to me more than 1 user that matchs that key and is not correct

Comment: take a look the logcat, the ge2 user belongs to the g8 key and that is incorrect, it should only say that belongs to ge2

Comment: what are you logging? (what are you writing inside `Log.d()`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184967/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-todd).

Comment: Log.d(TAG, " User : "+user+" not assisted to the event: "+eventKey);